# Error with two different generic types

Tags: java, generics, nodes

So, I understand this error message is telling me what is wrong, but I am having trouble determining why I am coming up with this error and how to resolve it:

constructor Node in class Node cannot be applied to given types
required: E#1
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where E#1,E#2 are type-variables:
    E#1 extends Object declared in class MyStack
    E#2 extends Object declared in class Node

I have implemented stacks in the past with linked lists and never ran into this before. I have included the first sections of code for my MyStack class and Node class, as I don't believe the methods contained are relevant. If they are I'm happy to edit them in. My main issue is I don't understand why it is making two separate generic types. I understand it is telling me that actual and formal argument lists differ in length, but how can that be and what could I do to resolve this?

```
public class MyStack<E> extends Node<E>{

//pieced together linked list
private int cnt;
private Node<E> head;


public MyStack() {
    head = null;
    cnt = 0;
}
```

Here is the Node Class.

```
public class Node <E>{ 



public Node<E> link;
public E item;

public Node(E data) {
    item = data;
    link = null;
}
```

Any clues as to why this is showing 2 different generic types would be helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is no no-argument constructor for `Node`, and `MyStack` extends `Node`, you'll need to specify how the constructor for `MyStack` is going to call the constructor for `Node`.  Currently, this won't compile because you don't have the `super` constructor call at the start of the constructor for `MyStack`.

Comment: Good call my friend! Thanks for the help! I've got it going now.